# Propeller Chip with Catalina C compiler

Tags: parallax

I am working on a project using multiple MEMs sensors that communicate to a microcontroller where the data is processed before sending it serially via RF.

I am using the Parallax Propeller Chip for it's ability to run multiple processes simultaneously. However, the SPIN language is quite slow and complex floating math algorithms get messy very quickly in SPIN. So I transitioned to the Catalina C compiler made for the Propeller but for the life of me cannot find any function libraries. I managed to toggle a few LEDs in C but am a long ways away from figuring out how to implement I2C, SPI, and serial communications in C. If you are familiar with this compiler, any pointers would be greatly greatly appreciated.

Cheers!
Jason

Comment: You will get more support from the Parallax forums: http://forums.parallax.com/forum.php

Answer (score 1):

There are no function libraries (at least that I could find a bit ago) for Catalina. It's write-your-own-everything, at this point.

---

Furthermore, I would suggest you not use Catalina, but rather use [prop-gcc](https://sites.google.com/site/propellergcc/).

However, both C compilers are very poorly documented, mostly in beta, and have almost no libraries available.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up, I guess I can stop my wild goose chase now!